# Is thunder an angel?

Tags: hadith, tafseer, hadith-interpretation, malaikah

Regarding this ayat of the Noble Qur'an:

> *13:13:
>
>   And the thunder declares His glory with His praise, and the angels too for awe of Him; and He sends the thunderbolts and smites with them whom He pleases, yet they dispute concerning Allah, and He is mighty in prowess.*

The Qur'an commentators have hadith saying that thunder is an angel.  Are these narrations authentic?

Baydawi comments on verse 13 of chapter (13) the Thunder-

> "Ibn 'Abbas asked the apostle of Allah about the thunder.
>   He told him, 'It is an angel who is in charge of the cloud, who (carries) with him swindles of fire by which he drives the clouds."'

al-Itqan" by Suyuti (part 4, p. 230) we read the following dialogue:

> *"On the authority of Ibn 'Abbas, he said the Jews came to the prophet (peace be upon him) and said, 'Tell us about the thunder. What is it?' He told them:
>   'It is one of Allah's angels in charge of the clouds. He carries in his hand a swindle of fire by which he pricks the clouds to drive them to where Allah has ordered them.'
>   They said to him, 'What is this sound that we hear?' He said: '(It is) his voice (The angel's voice)."'*

Comment: The hadith is in Jami' at-Tirmdihi http://sunnah.com/urn/741320.

Answer (score 4):

The aya doesn't mean that thunder is an angel:

> وَيُسَبِّحُ الرَّعْدُ بِحَمْدِهِ وَالْمَلَائِكَةُ مِنْ خِيفَتِهِ
>   وَيُرْسِلُ الصَّوَاعِقَ فَيُصِيبُ بِهَا مَنْ يَشَاءُ
>
> And the thunder declares His glory with His praise, and the angels too
>   for awe of Him; and He sends the thunderbolts and smites with them
>   whom He pleases, yet they dispute concerning Allah, and He is mighty
>   in prowess.

The aya means that the thunder declares the glory of Allah and his praise.  That doesn't imply that the thunder is an angel.  It's like in the aya:

> Do you not see that to Allah prostrates whoever is in the heavens and
>   whoever is on the earth and the sun, the moon, the stars, the
>   mountains, the trees, the moving creatures and many of the people? But
>   upon many the punishment has been justified. And he whom Allah
>   humiliates - for him there is no bestower of honor. Indeed, Allah does
>   what He wills.  22/18
>
> ---
>
> The seven heavens and the earth and whatever is in them exalt Him. And
>   there is not a thing except that it exalts [ Allah ] by His praise,
>   but you do not understand their [way of] exalting. Indeed, He is ever
>   Forbearing and Forgiving. 17/44

Here, the Sun and the Moon and trees are not angels, yet they prostrate to Allah.   But we don't know this can be not like our sujud (prostrates).

As for the hadith, I read that this hadith is authentic on some websites, and I read that is not in some others.  We need a student of Hadith terminology to tell us.

I found some explication of this is hadith.  I can't translate it, but one of them of ibn-taymya.  It's awesome (may someone translate for us):

> يقول شيخ الإسلام ابن تيمية في معنى الحديث :
>
> ---
>
> وقد روي عن بعض السلف أقوال
>   لا تخالف ذلك، كقول من يقول إنه (أي الرعد) اصطكاك أجرام السحاب بسبب
>   انضغاط الهواء فيه، فإن هذا لا يناقض ذلك لأن الرعد مصدر رعد يرعد رعداً،
>   وكذلك الراعد يسمى رعداً، كما يسمى العادل عدلاً، والحركة توجب الصوت،
>   والملائكة هي التي تحرك السحاب وتنقله من مكان إلى مكان، وكل حركة في
>   العالم العلوي والسفلي فهي عن الملائكة.

He said that some scholars of Salaf (older scholars than him) gave a scientific explication to thunder (as air compression, and things like that).  He said that this scientific explication doesn't conflict the explication in hadith because of a language-related reason.  (He explains it, but I can't translate it.)

I say: this hadith might be authentic or might be not, and even if it's authentic that doesn't mean we don't believe in science.  Like, in death, science gives us what he sees. And we know that there is angel of spirits that take our spirits out of our bodies.